# Check the number of times a branch has been locked and possible causes of lock Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, branch, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to check the number of times a branch has been locked in a given month in Azure DevOps? I know there is an Api that tells if a branch is locked or not. I am hoping there is a way to get the number of times branch has been locked and possible causes of the lock?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such REST API to get the number of times branch has been locked and possible causes of the lock.

The most possible way is to use the [Auditing logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), but per my test, it will also not include the logs of the lock branch operation.

If you want to help improve the Azure DevOps with this feature, you could post your idea here- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21&preview2=true

Comment: That's a bummer, I will see what I can find in the auditing logs. I was really hoping to get data on lock operations. I have posted the idea in the developer community. Thanks for the response.